# Get the current method name on my view to another function

Tags: php

I have this in my Controller:

```
public function send()
{
   $this->load->view('send');
}

public function edit()
{
   $this->load->view('edit');
}

public function changeForm()
{
   print_r('Current Location I am in'); //Wanted to get the current method I am in
}
```

So for example I am in the `edit` view, I wanted to get the `edit` to the `changeForm` is it possible? I tried `__FILE__`,`__FUNCTION__`,`__METHOD__` but it only gets to the current function, and it will only give me `changeForm` not the current Location I am in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are using those magic methods inside the changeForm which will tell you are currently in changeForm. Either you have to set some kind of a dynamic config parameter or static variable to keep track of the form/action you are in or if you are calling "changeForm" from the view (e.g.edit), then you can pass an argument to the call itself.